# Serial port - no output Penmount DMC9000

Tags: linux, io, serial-port, minicom

I'm trying to read some data from the some serial ports (I need them to deal with a touch screen controller).

What I'm basically doing is `cat /dev/ttyS0` to see what does the serial give as output when touching the screen.
I can `cat` (or `screen` or `minicom`) all 4 serial ports: `/dev/ttyS0` to `/dev/ttyS3`, but for all of them I get no output, even when physically touching the screen.

`cat /dev/ttyS0` (or any other ttyS*) just hangs and gives no output

Neither `cat /dev/ttyS0 | xxd` gives output. I have to end `cat` with `CTRL + C`

`screen /dev/ttyS0` hangs with no output, same for the other ttyS*

### Useful infos

#### OS

CentOS 7

#### ttyS in dmesg

```
[root@centos-t1 ~]# dmesg | grep -i 'ttys'
[    1.530144] 00:08: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4) is a 16550A
[    1.551401] 00:09: ttyS1 at I/O 0x2f8 (irq = 3) is a 16550A
[    1.572603] 00:0a: ttyS2 at I/O 0x3e8 (irq = 10) is a 16550A
[    1.593818] 00:0b: ttyS3 at I/O 0x2e8 (irq = 11) is a 16550A
```

#### List of ttyS*

```
[root@centos-t1 ~]# ls -la /dev/ttyS*
crw-rw----. 1 root dialout 4, 64 29 dic 09.57 /dev/ttyS0
crw-rw----. 1 root dialout 4, 65 29 dic 09.57 /dev/ttyS1
crw-rw----. 1 root dialout 4, 66 29 dic 09.57 /dev/ttyS2
crw-rw----. 1 root dialout 4, 67 29 dic 09.57 /dev/ttyS3
```

#### setserial output

```
[root@centos-t1 ~]# setserial -g /dev/ttyS*
/dev/ttyS0, UART: 16550A, Port: 0x03f8, IRQ: 4
/dev/ttyS1, UART: 16550A, Port: 0x02f8, IRQ: 3
/dev/ttyS2, UART: 16550A, Port: 0x03e8, IRQ: 10
/dev/ttyS3, UART: 16550A, Port: 0x02e8, IRQ: 11
```

#### Kernel

```
[root@centos-t1 ~]# uname -a
Linux centos-t1 3.10.0-327.3.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Dec 9 14:09:15 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

#### lsusb

```
[root@centos-t1 ~]# lsusb
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 05e3:0723 Genesys Logic, Inc. GL827L SD/MMC/MS Flash Card Reader
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 058f:5608 Alcor Micro Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0403:6001 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT232 Serial (UART) IC
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Please, note that PCI:004:002 is actually and RFID reader attached to the system. So it's not the serial I need to deal with - at the moment.

### Serial chip

Fintek F81866

### System

Embedded Touch Panel by Iei - AFL2-W10A-N28 [Product page](http://www.ieiworld.com/product_groups/industrial/content.aspx?gid=00001000010000000004&cid=08141356634833715309&id=0C326420517771211747) and [Datasheet](http://www.ieiworld.com/files/product/0C326431340434794446/catalog/en-US/AFL2-W10A_10A%20datasheet_201510.pdf)

### Touch screen controller

Penmount DMC9000 (attached via serial I suppose, since it isn't in the lsusb list)

Comment: Per [the PenMount 9000 Controller IC datasheet](http://www.salt.com.tw/en/wp-content/uploads/sites/5/2015/02/PenMount-9000-458-Datasheet-V2.04.pdf) it uses an RS-232 interface.

Comment: Is it the driver installed? `apt-cache search penmount  //   xserver-xorg-input-penmount - X.Org X server -- Penmount input driver`

Comment: OS: CentOS (so no apt commands)

Searching penmount:
`[root@centos-t1 ~]# yum search penmount
(...)
Warning: No matches found for: penmount
No matches found`
Unfortunately there are no matches found. I already downloaded before with another install the penmount driver, but without a serial communication it won't work

Comment: It's weird that CentOS does not have a package with the driver to this guy. I can´t even find the module name, since the last driver released by Advantech was in 2005, to be used with Red Hat 9. Before you try to go back to Windows Embedded, is there a way to test with Debian and `xserver-xorg-input-penmount` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to fix the problem.
The serial port wasn't correctly detected beacause of an irq problem.

Here is how I've fixed it:

1. Switched from CentOS 7 to Debian 8.2 (jessie)
   With the following kernel (latest available): `Linux debian-term1 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt20-1+deb8u1 (2015-12-14) x86_64 GNU/Linux`
2. Temporarily enabled the touch screen via `setserial /dev/ttyS3 irq 0` (this actually is the solution)
3. Downloaded the Penmount drivers from [this website](http://support.advantech.com/support/DownloadSRDetail_New.aspx?SR_ID=1-11D35D5&Doc_Source=Download), configured the penmount.ini to disable the noisy beep sound (via `BeepType=0`) and installed the driver module via `./install.sh`
4. Calibrated the touchscreen via `gCal 9 /etc/penmount/penmount.dat` (had to start the X server, it's a GTK application, obviously)
5. Made the changes permanent by adding a `/usr/share/penmount/penmount.sh` script containing the `setserial` command above and inserted it in `/etc/init.d/lightdm` `start)` section. I know it's dirty, but I'm planning to change it soon.

Thank you guys for the help, now my Penmount DMC9000 works like a charm!